# Creating a bigger data frame by joining multiple data frames

Tags: r

I currently have multiple data frames (named cont, cont2 .... cont7), and need to combine them

Each data frame has 2 columns; date and a mean temperature value (taken from a netcdf file)

The dates are monthly values, in 
cont = 1951-1 to 1960-12 
cont7 = 2011-1 to 2014-12
(basically monthly values split into groups of 10 years, from Jan 1951- Dec 2014)

How can I extent my data frame so all values are in 1 table? I want to make it continuous so as to plot a time series

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I do not understand your problem correctly, but would not rbind() do the Job?

```
cont_all <- rbind(cont1,cont2,cont3,cont4,con5,cont6,cont7)
```

Comment: Usually an answer doesn't end with a question mark. And it is better to get some clarity from the OP instead of guessing in the answers section.